# Export MongoDB symbol in Package in Meteor 0.6.5

Tags: package, meteor

I need to use MongoDB driver in Meteor because I want to use [Grid](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/grid.html) in my application. Before Meteor 0.6.5, I managed to have a mongodb as a package, and it worked fine.

But after the update, with the new Package system, I cannot make it to work. Here is my package.js (in `myAppFolder/packages/mongodb/`), I also did `meteor add mongodb`

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "Mongodb driver"
});

Npm.depends({'mongodb': '1.3.18'});

Package.on_use(function(api){
    MongoDB = Npm.require("mongodb");
    console.log(MongoDB, '--------------');

    api.export('MongoDB', 'server');
});
```

I can see that the console log prints something when I start the server, but then in my application code at runtime, the value of MongoDB is undefined, the same thing for `Package.mongodb.MongoDB` . It seems to me that these values are assigned to undefined somehow.

If someone knows how to use the already included MongoDB driver in the mongo-livedata package, it would be a better solution.

Comment: have a look at the CollectionFS project. They do something similar https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS

Comment: I did. The solution of this project is manually manage chunks and files collections, which does not use the [Grid](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/grid.html) interface in GridFS. I dont want to manually manage 2 collections because it can be error prone, delete in one and forget to delete in the other for example. Grid offers a more convenient abstraction layer to manipulate files, exactly what I need. (I will change my question to Grid instead of GridFS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it works if you do it in the `package.js` file; it appears you have to use a separate file. I did something similar to get the [csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv) package, in the following way:

`package.js`:

```
Npm.depends({
    csv: "0.3.5"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.add_files('server.js', 'server');

    api.export('csv');
});
```

`server.js`:

```
csv = Npm.require('csv');
```

This is Meteor 0.6.5+ specific. They have a section in the docs about it now: http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages

Like you said though, you should be able to `Npm.require` the same mongodb package that Meteor is already using, and save an additional npm install. For example, the `mongo-livedata` package exports something called `MongoInternals`, and you may be able to dig in to it and find out how to pull out the mongo driver:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo-livedata/package.js